# Express overwrites react-router client side routes

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I don't want to use server side rendering because it is an absolute pain to get working and I've gotten everything working without it.

However if I make a new url like `/test` and visit localhost:3000/test I get `Cannot get /test`

This is how my index page is being served up

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html')
})
```

**routes file**

```
const routes = (
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={ AppContainer }>
        <IndexRoute component={ RegistrationContainer }/>
        <Route path="test" component={ StripeContainer }/>
      </Route>
  </div>
)

export default routes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on this right now and I think you'll need to declare the `/test` path before the React route.

How I'm going to implement it in my app is declare some routes in Express for user login and then have a catchall at the end to send anything else to React.

Something like

```
app.get('/login', function(...));
app.get('/logout', function(...));
app.get('*', <TO-REACT>);
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about dealing with this issue but it should work.

Let me know how it works for you or if you foresee any issues using this.

Update:
I can confirm that this is working for me now.
Here are abbreviated versions of my express routes file and base React file.

***routes***

```
// redirects any requests to root of domain to React (a polling app)
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/polls');
  });

// authentication routes
app.get('/login' function(....));
app.get('/logout' function(....));
app.get('/login/callback' function(....));
app.get('/login/authorise' function(....));

// React catch all route
app.get('*', function(....{sendfile....});
```

***base react file***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Redirect, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

const PollListScreen = require('./PollListScreen.js');
const PollAdd = require('./PollAdd.js');

ReactDOM.render(
  (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/polls' component={PollListScreen} />
    <Route path='/polls/new' component={PollAdd} />
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Using this approach, how do you define a route for static content (like images) using express.static ? Right now if I try to GET /images/logo.png server returns my index.html

Comment: I have the following before my routes - 

`app.use('/css', express.static(path + '/static/css'));`