# Routes are not defined in react build : react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<Router>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<h2>Page not found</h2>} />
 </Routes>
</Router>
```

this is how i have defined the routes in v6, this works perfect in development, but in build version only index route that is "/" loads, and others routes dont work saying : The requested path cannot be found.
[image]

screenshot is of build version

Comment: This should answer you question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669748/express-overwrites-react-router-client-side-routes

Comment: i dont how this is answering my question, can you please explain

Comment: It seems you need to configure the server to redirect the nested routes to the root "/" directory where your app is running.

Answer (score 0):

React Router is a client-side routing solution, as the name suggests all the "routings" are done on the user's browser.

When a user request to access `/login`, which is what you are doing in the question, the browser by default expects to access `/login.html`. It requests the server to send him such file, but since all the routings are done on the client-side, the server has no knowledge of it nor has `/login.html` in hand.

What you should do is add a wild card expression on your server side, to send all unmapped requests back to the client so that React Router can pick up the path changes and do its job.

Comment: but there is no server side involved in this app, even if i manually type the route /login it is still showing the same error. only the home route that is "/" is getting rendered and all other routes are undefined

Comment: If there is no server involved, then how do you deploy the application?

Comment: i am deploying a build that i got after npm run build, and the app routing is not working even if the pages are static and has nothing to do with the server

Comment: After you run `build`, did you put the build files anywhere? Or you just click the `index.html`?

Comment: serving the build through npx serve build and putting the files in a shared hosting results the same error of path 404 not found

Comment: By "shared hosting", which service do you use? This part is the server-side I'm talking about. Even a fully static website will have a server at the backline to handle requests. At least, it has to manage to map `/` to `index.html`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241730/discussion-between-akhil-bisht-and-matthew-kwong).